# Why isn't this table cell getting the correct class applied?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an HTML page (PHP, really) with a table cell that contains a graphic and has two background graphics (one repeating gradient, one right aligned). It has a second table cell that contains a styled list. Because I need to use PHP to evaluate the image path, I need to define certain styles inside the HTML, instead of in a separate .css file. Can anyone help me out and explain why the styles are being correctly applied to the li elements, but not to the table cell with class logoHeader? (li.white is defined in the linked css file, as it doesn't require any php for path evaluation.) I'm a server-side programmer, and although I can do basic css I don't have the greatest grasp on rules of inheritance.

Here's the rendered source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>
 <base href="http://mysite.com/mobile" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <title>Home</title> 

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/mobile/css/editor_content.css" type="text/css" />
 <style>
  <!-- need to define these styles here because we can't use php in the css - it doesn't evaluate -->

  td.logoHeader {
   background: url(/images/mobile/transparentLeavesRight.png) top right no-repeat,  
               url(/images/mobile/transparentLeavesGradient.png) top left repeat-x;
               text-align:center;}


  li.blue {
   background-image:url(/images/mobile/arrow.png);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:right; 
   background-color:#013799;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td class="logoHeader"><img src="/images/mobile/logoCopy.png" alt="Senior Living" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<ul class="pureCssMenu">
    <li class="white">1-800-888-8888 </li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/care-types">CARE TYPES</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/find-a-community">FIND A COMMUNITY</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/programs">PROGRAMS</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/gallery">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried defining the class as just .logoHeader (as opposed to td.logoHeader) - same results. It doesn't get the style. Here's a firebug screenshot showing what it's getting:
[image]

Comment: +1 for showing the full markup and Firebug inspection attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can apply the styles using that class if I remove your comment in the Style section. CSS comments should be this style: `/* Comment */`

Edit: added example: http://jsfiddle.net/FMwRr/

Comment: That did it. Can you explain why it only ignored the first style? The li.blue style WAS being applied correctly, in spite of the badly-formatted comment.

Comment: Browsers try and render bad/broken CSS as best they can, Chrome looks like it recovered and went on to apply the next style correctly. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Graham - still not sure I understand. When my comment was formatted incorrectly, I had two styles. One was ignored and one was applied. When I formatted the comment correctly, both styles were applied. Why wouldn't both styles be ignored if the comment was the problem? (Also, never seen jsfiddle before - very cool.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll never understand that; as far as I'm concerned if something is broken it should be broken so it can be debugged, rather than the browser compensating. Oh, well.

Comment: In this case Chrome's CSS parser choked on the incorrect comment, causing it to mess up the next CSS rule that was in close proximity (the table class). I'm not sure how exactly Chrome's CSS parser is built, but it was good enough to apply the NEXT style correctly, only treating the previous css rule as malformed due to the comment. When writing a parser it's a good idea to build in a certain level of error correction/handling so one mistake doesn't stop the whole thing.